# $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}=1$ vs $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{p^n}=q$

Tags: real-analysis, soft-question, lp-spaces

It just occurred to me that conjugate exponents, i.e. $p,q\in(1,+\infty)$ such that $$\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q} =1$$
also satisfy the relations:

- $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{p^n}=q;$
- $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{q^n}=p.$

I never saw this fact used in the study of $L^p$ spaces... does anyone know any application of these relations in that context?

Answer (score 6):

In the study of $L^p$ spaces, I think this implies, e.g., that a particular generalization of Hölder's inequality holds: Let $f_n \in L^{p^n}$ for $n \in \mathbb N$. Then

$$\left\Vert \prod_{n=0}^\infty f_n\right\Vert_{1/q} \leq \prod_{n=0}^\infty \Vert f_n \Vert_{p^n}.$$

This can be proven by passing to the limit [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder%27s_inequality#Generalization_of_H%C3%B6lder's_inequality). I'm sure that one can construct more similarly artificial applications of this result.

Edit: It turns out that what I stated here is actually a special case of [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/308058/513190).

Comment: See this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/307690/620957